# "How to fix When installing bundle I receive errors in Gemfile pg "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, debian

I am trying to do `bundle install` on my path for my rails application via Debian

Tried using `gem install pg --force` and `gem install pg -v '1.1.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`

Tried using `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`

Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 libpq5 amd64 9.6.11-0+deb9u1404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:1::204 80]
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 libpq-dev amd64 9.6.11-0+deb9u1 404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:1::204 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/postgresql-9.6/libpq5_9.6.11-0+deb9u1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:1::204 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/postgresql-9.6/libpq-dev_9.6.11-0+deb9u1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:1::204 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

saishbhende24@DESKTOP-ELUO53H:/mnt/c/saishrails/r35.1/r5.1$ `gem install pg -v '1.1.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
/home/saishbhende24/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:76: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/saishbhende24/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

> ```
> saishbhende24@DESKTOP-ELUO53H:/mnt/c/saishrails/r35.1/r5.1$ gem install pg Building native extensions. This could take a while...
> ```
>
> /home/saishbhende24/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:76:
>   warning: Insecure world writable dir
>   /home/saishbhende24/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin in PATH, mode 040777
>   ERROR:  Error installing pg:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: /home/saishbhende24/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/pg-1.1.4/ext
> ```
>
> /home/saishbhende24/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby -I
>   /home/saishbhende24/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
>   ./siteconf20190805-760-x2yfpd.rb extconf.rb checking for pg_config...
>   no No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again
>   with  --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config checking for libpq-fe.h...
>   no Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>           --with-opt-dir
>           --without-opt-dir
>           --with-opt-include
>           --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>           --with-opt-lib
>           --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>           --with-make-prog
>           --without-make-prog
>           --srcdir=.
>           --curdir
>           --ruby=/home/saishbhende24/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
>           --with-pg
>           --without-pg
>           --enable-windows-cross
>           --disable-windows-cross
>           --with-pg-config
>           --without-pg-config
>           --with-pg_config
>           --without-pg_config
>           --with-pg-dir
>           --without-pg-dir
>           --with-pg-include
>           --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
>           --with-pg-lib
>           --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
>
> To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log
>   which can be found here:
>
> /home/saishbhende24/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/pg-1.1.4/mkmf.log
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /home/saishbhende24/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/pg-1.1.4 for inspection.
>   Results logged to
>   /home/saishbhende24/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/pg-1.1.4/gem_make.out

Expected result is to install bundle successfully.

Comment: Can you post the complete stacktrace of error?

Comment: @AsimHashmi I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pg was installed and for some reason I had

```
./channels
```

It must be `//= require tree` so it can grab all files from the js folder.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a package. The `pg` gem depends upon `libpq-dev`

Try

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Comment: I think your system is not properly updated, I edited my answer.

Comment: It seems that you don't have `postgresql` installed on your system, I updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This command solved my problem:
`sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev`
and then `bundle`